# Python re findall using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a large string stored in a variable and i want to use re search using regular expressions to remove all junk text and show only text that has

> release/somefilehere

and it must be seperated by commas e.g.

> release/somefilehere1,release/somefilehere2,release/somefilehere3

The re search should not return duplicate paths so it shouldn't return

> release/somefilehere1,release/somefilehere1

I really am terrible with regular expressions can anyone help me out?

The string stored within the variable is this:

`/testing","displayId":"release/testing","latestChangeset":"12d7917fe9c78efa898e7ef45cf21be2ac727a75","isDefault":false},{
"id":"refs/heads/release/xzczx","displayId":"release/xzczx","latestChangeset":"12d7917fe9c78efa898e7ef45cf21be2ac727a75",
"isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/release/a.aa.a.2","displayId":"release/a.aa.a.2","latestChangeset":"c1c2c7d7741e4779
11de72154ad2e178a1bf793c","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/dev","displayId":"dev","latestChangeset":"3d432713d1a22be5
9a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7d","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/release/1a1","displayId":"release/1a1","latestChangeset":"
3d432713d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7d","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/release/aaaa","displayId":"release/aaaa","
latestChangeset":"3d432713d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7d","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/release/another_release"
,"displayId":"release/another_release","latestChangeset":"3d432713d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7d","isDefault":false},{"
id":"refs/heads/release/asdasdasd","displayId":"release/asdasdasd","latestChangeset":"3d432713d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d8723
2ca7d","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/release/my_branch","displayId":"release/my_branch","latestChangeset":"3d43271
3d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7d","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/release/one_last_test","displayId":"release/one_l
ast_test","latestChangeset":"3d432713d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7d","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/release/pleas
e_work","displayId":"release/please_work","latestChangeset":"3d432713d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7d","isDefault":false}
,{"id":"refs/heads/release/qqqqq","displayId":"release/qqqqq","latestChangeset":"3d432713d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7d
","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/release/test_branch","displayId":"release/test_branch","latestChangeset":"3d432713
d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7d","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/release/wwwwwwwwwwwwwwooorrrrrrrr","displayId":"re
lease/wwwwwwwwwwwwwwooorrrrrrrr","latestChangeset":"3d432713d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7d","isDefault":false},{"id":"r
efs/heads/release/zzzasdasda","displayId":"release/zzzasdasda","latestChangeset":"3d432713d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7
d","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/release/zzzsersfawda","displayId":"release/zzzsersfawda","latestChangeset":"3d432
713d1a22be59a17ebdebfa298d87232ca7d","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/prog_D_2a_aa_21_T1aa_joshg","displayId":"
prog_D_2a_aa_21_T1aa_joshg","latestChangeset":"c3d2cc2d793c7ea7e797c2444f2aa391cac94aba","isDefault":false},{"id":"
refs/heads/prog_D_2a_a1_21_T5727_joshg","displayId":"prog_D_2a_a1_21_T5727_joshg","latestChangeset":"282aafea
7eca8439df8baea9a7e1fa429f531123","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/prog_B_2a_19_21_DIAMOND-5a7_edwardb","displayId":
"prog_B_2a_19_21_DIAMOND-5a7_edwardb","latestChangeset":"cf78a3735cf758dd3af7d31c5574e247feabdbe9","isDefault":false},{"
id":"refs/heads/prog_D_2a_a2_21_T5727_joshg","displayId":"prog_D_2a_a2_21_T5727_joshg","latestChangeset":"247
ada79c2db2f9deae42253598aa7dd51acaaa2","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/prog_D_2a_19_2a_T5727_joshg","displayId
":"prog_D_2a_19_2a_T5727_joshg","latestChangeset":"9f45a81f9e7db7ad5b777a119ba3a8f55d4bdfc1","isDefault":false},{"i
d":"refs/heads/prog_D_2a_19_21_T5727_joshg","displayId":"prog_D_2a_19_21_T5727_joshg","latestChangeset":"8d79
fa11f7f2b93cf4957c778f1e7e1bc2824ed9","isDefault":false},{"id":"refs/heads/prog_D_2a_18_21_T5727_joshg","displayId"
:"prog_D_2a_18_21_T5727_joshg","latestChangeset":"5a838d357f137e77cbace8ca4fd74e7bff5b4daa","isDefault":false},{"id
":"refs/heads/prog_D_2a_17_T5727_joshg","displayId":"prog_D_2a_17_T5727_joshg","latestChangeset":"17b3af495f4
efbd9feffd25d728ea7a4c3dd784a","isDefault":false}],"start":2,"nextPageStart":a5}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> print(re.findall("\"(release/.+?)\"", text))
>>> ['release/testing', 'release/xzczx', 'release/a.aa.a.2', 'release/1a1', 'release/aaaa', 'release/another_release', 'release/asdasdasd', 'release/my_branch', 'release/please_work', 'release/qqqqq', 'release/test_branch', 'release/zzzasdasda', 'release/zzzsersfawda']
```

Comment: that's a good start but I only want strings that start with release and not anything before it e.g.   'refs/heads/release/xzczx' should be 'release/xzczx'

Comment: perfect Thank you!!! i was expecting a monster of a regex but this doesnt seem to long winded!